# Axios promise not resolving, always pending

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, axios

I'm not sure but i cant get the life of me to get this to resolve. its always pending. I'm not the best with promises so please help me out.

```
export async function getQuotes() {
  const options = {
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-host": API_URL,
      "x-rapidapi-key": API_KEY,
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
  };

  let res = await axios
    .post(API_URL, {}, options)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

  return res;
}
```

and this is how i'm calling it:

```
const new_data = dataApi.getQuotes();
console.log(new_data);
```

with the new_data variable, i'd like to access the data that was returned. I keep getting back pending promises instead.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, async functions return a promise that resolves to their return value. In order to access the data, you have to wrap it in another async function and call await or use [`.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

```js
// Either:
async function main() {
    const new_data = await dataApi.getQuotes();
    console.log(new_data);
}
// or
dataApi.getQuotes().then(new_data => console.log(new_data));
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: this definitely helps. I'm able to access the data from the "then" callback function. But my question after that is, why can't i access the response data outside of the callback?
if i defined a variable and then in the then callback, making that variable equal the response.data, it then resolves to null. So the data is only available in the callback but i'm just not sure why it can't be accessed outside the "then".

Comment: The code after the `then` runs before the code inside the `then` since the call to `then` doesn't block code execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait until the promise has been fulfilled and then process the data as follows:

```
dataApi.getQuotes()
    .then(function(new_data) {
        console.log(new_data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
       // error handling
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use async/await or promises (.then and .catch) - but not both at the same time. You should also know that an async function always returns a Promise, so you can use it with the then/catch syntax if you want.

```
// Call with the then/catch syntax
dataApi.getQuotes()
   .then((data) => console.log(data))
   .catch((err) => console.error(err))

// Is the same that this call with async await
async function main() {
  try {
    const data = await dataApi.getQuotes();
    console.log(data)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

About your function, you're using async/await here. So you may not use then/catch but await in its body.

```
export async function getQuotes() {
  const options = {
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-host": API_URL,
      "x-rapidapi-key": API_KEY,
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
  };

  try {
     let res = await axios.post(API_URL, {}, options);
     console.log(response);
   catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
   }

  return res;
}
```

Comment: You can use await and then/catch, it's just that it's a bit redundant.